# Unable to get fillable empty text fields in hyperref forms inside tabular environment with XeTeX

Tags: tables, xetex, hyperref, forms

I need to get fillable text fields inside tabular environment and since I use other language scripts other than English I need to compile my document using XeTeX engine. The nearest post to this question I have found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249349/26295), but this has been more than 3 years and 7 months now. The post confirmed the case that it does not work with XeTeX engine, I look forward to any update on this issue:

Below is my MWE:

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry} %showframe
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
  \textbf{No} & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Code} & \textbf{Request Date} & \textbf{Source} & \textbf{Issue Date} & \textbf{Notes} \\
  \TextField[backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30,height=20pt,width=0.05\textwidth,default=1]{} &
\TextField[backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30,height=20pt,width=0.2\textwidth]{} & \TextField[backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30,height=20pt,width=0.05\textwidth]{} &
\TextField[backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30,height=20pt,width=0.1\textwidth]{} &
\TextField[backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30,height=20pt,width=0.1\textwidth]{} &
                                                                                                                \TextField[backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30,height=20pt,width=0.1\textwidth]{} & \TextField[backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30,height=20pt,width=0.2\textwidth]{} \\

    \TextField[backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30,height=20pt,width=0.05\textwidth,default=2]{} &
\TextField[backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30,height=20pt,width=0.2\textwidth]{} & \TextField[backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30,height=20pt,width=0.05\textwidth]{} &
\TextField[backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30,height=20pt,width=0.1\textwidth]{} &
\TextField[backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30,height=20pt,width=0.1\textwidth]{} &
\TextField[backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30,height=20pt,width=0.1\textwidth]{} & \TextField[backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,bordercolor=gray!30,height=20pt,width=0.2\textwidth]{} \\
\end{tabular}  

\end{Form}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: xetex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Sorry but do you really think that an example trying to create about 100 (or more) textfields can be called "minimal"?

Comment: some redundant code is removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Textfields musst have a (unique) name, either throught the label argument or with the name key. With it it works fine for me with xelatex on texlive 2018:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry} %showframe
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\begin{tabular}{c}
  \textbf{No}\\ 
  \TextField[name=r1,backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,
             bordercolor=gray!30,height=20pt,width=0.2\textwidth]{} \\
  \TextField[name=r2,backgroundcolor=white,borderwidth=1,
             bordercolor=gray!30,height=20pt,width=0.2\textwidth]{} \\

\end{tabular}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]